# Compose: Inherit TextStyle from another TextStyle

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In my app, I have some Styles which inherit from another Style like this one:

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="RegularM">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/regular</item>
</style>

<style name="ListRow" parent="RegularM">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

This makes a `ListRow` entry a black-colored text with 18sp and uses a regular font.

So, now I convert this one to compose.

**Fonts.kt**

```
val Regular = FontFamily(
     Font(R.font.regular),
)

val RegularM = TextStyle(
     fontFamily = Regular,
     fontSize = 18.sp
)
```

So far, so good.

Now I want to create the `ListRow` TextStyle:

```
val ListRow = TextStyle(
    color = Black,
    ? inherit from RegularM
)
```

But I can't inherit from `RegularM`. I have to retype each property for the `ListRow` TextStyle. But this seem's to be wrong.

How I can inherit from the `RegularM`, or is using TextStyle for this one the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TextStyle` is not a data class, but still has `copy(...)` method implemented which you can use exactly for this issue:

```
var ListRow = RegularM.copy(color = Black)
```

Comment: Thank you, sometimes it is easier as it looks like

Answer (score 2):

With the `TestStyle` you can use the `copy` method [as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68830532/2016562) by @Philip but you can also use the [**`merge`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/TextStyle#merge) method.

Example:

```
Text(text = "This is my text",
    style = ( 
      RegularM.merge(TextStyle(color = Black))
    )
)
```